# how to update columns of datatable in dataset if the table is modified at the database file

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, dataset

I have created a SQL Server database file (`.mdf`) and added tables to it defining their columns. Then I added a dataset to my project linked to the database file, later on I found that I have to modify the db file and add some columns to the table, but the changes done on the db file doesn't reflect on the dataset until I delete the datatable in it and re-add it.

Is there any way to update the dataset without deleting and re-adding?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you must modify the SelectCommand of your TableAdapter.
And then you can add the new columns in your DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh dataset You can Reset dataSet and fill it again.

```
this.YourDataSet.Reset();
this.YourTableAdapter.Fill(this.YourDataSet.table);
```